# Fusion Chart swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, fusioncharts

I have tried to do a fusion chart swap but asp doesn't like doing that. So the next best thing is to have the fusion chart render, and then with a onmousedown, replace the chart with an image. Only this isn't working as well. I have tried adding div's around the code and using id's, but the swapping isn't working. I have used the 'popChartDiv' in the document.popChartDiv.src, but this ID is what is calling the rendering for the Literal3. I am not sure about how to switch Literal3 with the 2 div's below it (testimage.png and testimage1.png). It seems the chart is the focal point and the images are unable to override the chart. I have tried using z-index as well but that didn't work. So I'm stuck.

```
<div style="width:798px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; height:250px; float:left; overflow:hidden;" id="popChartDiv">
    <script src="../../Dashboard/Charts/FusionCharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="popChartContainer"></div>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" Visible="true" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
         <div id="line3ChartContainer"></div>
         <asp:Literal ID="Literal9" Visible="true" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
         <img src="/images/testimage.png" width="798" height="250" name="swap"/>
</div>
<div style="width:38px; height:250px; float:left;">
    <img src="../../images/labortab.png" style="float:left; width:38px; height:125px;" id="labor" onmousedown="document.swap.src='/images/testimage.png';"/>
    <img src="../../images/odctab.png" style="float:left; width:38px; height:125px;" id="odc" onmousedown="document.swap.src='/images/testimage1.png';"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#labor').hover(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', '/images/labortabhover.png');
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', '/images/labortab.png');
        });

        $('#odc').hover(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', '/images/odctabhover.png');
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', '/images/odctab.png');
        });


        </script>
</div>
```

Comment: WHat is the ID of your chart? IS it `line3Chart`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering Flash based charts, it might be that the window mode (`wMode`) is set to `window`. There is an [Adobe help article on SWF stacking order](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/swf-file-ignores-stacking-order.html) that states that the z-Index of SWF objects are ignored when window mode parameter is set to `window`.

In pure ASP.NET (C#), if you are using the `RenderChart` method, then setting the ninth parameter to true (or false) should help you. Refer to relevant section in the [creating first chart using C# documentation article of FusionCharts](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/guide-for-web-developers/csnet/CS_BasicExample.html).

In case you are more comfortable working with JavaScript, you may try calling `setTransparent(false);` on chart to set wMode to opaque or transparent.

Assuming that your chart id is `line3Chart`, the code would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Add this code snippet. Make sure to replace
    // "line3Chart with correct chart id
    FusionCharts("line3Chart").setTransparent(false);

    $('#labor').hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '/images/labortabhover.png');
    }, function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '/images/labortab.png');
    });

    $('#odc').hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '/images/odctabhover.png');
    }, function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '/images/odctab.png');
    });
</script>
```